# kncokout, flat ui and bootstrap binding issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, durandal, flat

We are using flat ui in my project and we have some ui issues.

1. File upload control issue.
2. Radio buttons/check boxes/drop downs css issue.

File upload:

Normal html (design time) when we select file it's showing the change and remove button with file name. Whereas in durandal application it's not showing change/remove and file name in control, always showing select button only.

HTML content.

```
<div class="pull-right col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-group">
    <label>Upload Condo Logo</label>
    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="form-control uneditable-input" data-trigger="fileinput">
                <span class="fui-clip fileinput-exists"></span>
                <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="input-group-btn btn-file">
                <span class="btn btn-default fileinput-new" 
                      data-role="select-file">Select file</span>
                <span class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" 
                      data-role="change">
                    <span class="fui-gear"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Change
                </span>
                <input type="file" id="fitest" name="...">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" 
                   data-dismiss="fileinput">
                    <span class="fui-trash"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Remove
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check box/radio button/dropdown

Check box:

Normal html page displaying proper style and color.

In Project, controls are not displaying and binding also not working. If we remove css its working fine.

Durandal page html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1" 
       data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedCondos, attr: { value : id }" />
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: What file upload control are you using? Is it built into Flat UI (sorry, haven't used Flat UI)?  It would seem that you may need to inject the required JS to make the file upload work into the attached function of your viewmodel.  If you can share what control you're using that might help with an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I have already copied html in my question. Please let me know if i missed anything here.

Comment: I'm going to have to download FlatUI and play with it to see if I can replicate what you're seeing here.